# D minMax function implementation

Tags: unit-testing, template, iteration, d

I happened to need to find both the maximum and the minimum of an array, so I decided to implement a `minMax` function in D.

Questions:

1. Is this an efficient implementation?
2. Is it readable?
3. Any general feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import std.range;
import std.traits;
import std.typecons;
import std.functional;

class EmptyContainerException : Exception {
    this(string msg, string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__) {
        super(msg, file, line);
    }
}

// returns a tuple containing the minimum and maximum elements of a finite InputRange
template minMax(alias pred = "a") {
    alias map = unaryFun!pred;

    auto minMax(Range)(Range r)
    if(isInputRange!Range && !isInfinite!Range && is(typeof(map(r.front)))) {
        if(r.empty) {
            throw new EmptyContainerException(
                "minMax expected a container with at least 1 element, got an empty container."
            );
        }
        auto front = r.front;
        auto frontMap = map(front);

        auto min = front;
        auto max = front;
        auto minMap = frontMap;
        auto maxMap = frontMap;

        r.popFront;
        while(!r.empty) {
            front = r.front;
            frontMap = map(front);
            if(frontMap > maxMap) {
                max = front;
                maxMap = frontMap;
            }
            if(frontMap < minMap) {
                min = front;
                minMap = frontMap;
            }
            r.popFront;
        }
        return tuple!("min", "max")(min, max);
    }
}

unittest {
    import std.exception : assertThrown;

    int[] test1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    auto test1result = test1.minMax;
    assert(test1result.min == 1 && test1result.max == 5);

    string test2 = "Hello, World!";
    auto test2result = test2.minMax;
    assert(test2result.min == ' ' && test2result.max == 'r');

    int[] test3 = [];
    assertThrown!EmptyContainerException(test3.minMax);

    string[] test4 = ["who", "is", "the", "longest", "word"];
    auto test4result = test4.minMax!"a.length";
    assert(test4result.min == "is" && test4result.max == "longest");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this an efficient implementation?

Yup. It calls `map` exactly once per item, and otherwise does nothing but the regular range calls. A specialized implementation could be more efficient in some cases (but probably only if using vector instructions), as could a parallel implementation, but neither of these have the genericity that your code does.

> Is it readable?

Absolutely, it's some of the most readable code I've seen. The content of the loop is somewhat dense. You could perhaps make it less dense like this:

```
    auto front = tuple!("elem", "map")(r.front, map(r.front));
    auto min = front;
    auto max = front;

    r.popFront;
    foreach (e; r) {
        front = tuple(e, map(e));
        if(front.map > max.map) max = front;
        if(front.map < min.map) min = front;
    }
    return tuple!("min", "max")(min.elem, max.elem);
```

Apart from that, I got nuthin'.

> Any general feedback is appreciated.

As hinted at in the section above, instead of `while (!empty)`, you might want to use `foreach`. This reduces your code by one line (`r.popFront()`), and makes it clearer that you're going to iterate over every element of the range. It shouldn't change the performance of the code in any way.

You should put an `if (is(typeof(unaryFun!pred)))` constraint on the template, so the user of the function gets an error message on the line where he or she tries to instantiate it with `arr.minMax!"invalid string"`.

Also, the name `pred` is wrong - a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) is a boolean-valued function, like `equal`, `same color` or `contains bees`. I'd call it `Fn` or `Fun`.

As a minor nit, I'd also change the name of `map`, probably to `fn` or `fun` (note the difference in capitalization). This because I kept conflating your `map` with `std.algorithm.map`. The concept is correct, but essentially the name is already taken.

All in all, very good - my only comments are essentially nitpicks.